# separation of variables in Heat equation with source

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, initial-value-problems

[image]

And this my basic attempt. My question is how to deal with source in terms of the solution itself? Usually, I solved this source term first but in this case, I don't know how to continue writing...And to confirm if I am on the right way?
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: I would suggest writing substituting the ansatz $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ into the PDE, and separate the equation. In the work that you posted, I do not see the ODE that $X(x)$ must satisfy or the ODE that $T(t)$ must satisfy.

Comment: Actually I do see the ODE that $X(x)$ must satisfy or $\varphi(x)$ must satisfy. Please write down the equation that $A(t)$ must satisfy, this should clarify things for you.

Comment: My question is if $u(x,t) = \phi (x)\psi(t)$ is only the solution for homogeneous problems, then how could I just write it in this way under this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDE is linear homogeneous in $u(x,t)$ the boundary conditions are homogeneous Dirichlet.

I substitute the ansatz $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ into the pde and divide by $u(x,t)$ and obtain

\begin{align}
T'(t)/T(t)-k X''(x)/X(x)=\gamma
\end{align}

for the above to hold we must have $X''(x)/X(x)=\lambda$, $X(x)$ must satisfy the homogeneous boundary conditions, so we get a family of solutions
to the eigenvalue problem
\begin{align}
X_{n}(x)=\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right),\,\,\,\lambda_{n}=-n^{2}\pi^{2}/L^{2}
\end{align}

substituting back we have

\begin{align}
\frac{T'_{n}(t)}{T_{n}(t)}-k\lambda_{n}=\gamma
\end{align}

which gives $T_{n}(t)=\exp(\left(\gamma+k\lambda_{n}\right)t)$

\begin{align}
u(x,t)=\exp(\gamma\, t)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}\exp(k\lambda_{n}t)\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})
\end{align}

With hindsight one can also make the change of variables $u(x,t)=\exp(-\gamma t)w(x,t)$, one sees, for which one has

\begin{align}
u_{t}=-\gamma\exp(-\gamma t)w(x,t)+\exp(-\gamma t)w_{t}=-\gamma u+\exp(-\gamma t)w_{t}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
u_{t}+\gamma u=\exp(-\gamma t)w_{t}
\end{align}

The PDE in $w(x,t)$ is the one that you are familiar with

\begin{align}
w_{t}-kw_{xx}=0
\end{align}

I hope one of these two answers helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but may I ask did you miss a k in the third line?

Comment: Oh I definitely did, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Fixed the mistake.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate